# mutable record fields and { x with ... }

Tags: ocaml, record, semantics, mutable

I've been reading through the `ocaml` docs but I can't the part that explains how `{ x with ... }` works around mutable fields.  The [closest I've found](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) says

> ## 6.7 Expressions
>
> ```
> expr := ...
>     ∣ { expr with  field =  expr  { ; field =  expr }  [;] }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ## Records
>
> The expression `{ expr with  field1 =  expr1 ; … ;  fieldn =  exprn }` builds a fresh record with `fields field1 …  fieldn` equal to `expr1 …  exprn`, and all other fields having the same value as in the record `expr`. In other terms, it returns a **shallow copy** of the record `expr`, except for the fields `field1 …  fieldn`, which are initialized to `expr1 …  exprn`.

That "shallow copy" verbiage could be interpreted to mean that `mutable` fields not mentioned share storage space or could refer to nested records.  When I test (using "The OCaml toplevel, version 4.00.1") thus

```
type t = { mutable x : int; mutable y: int }
let a = {x=42;y=123}
let b = { a with y=124}
let _ = a.x <- 43
let _ = Printf.printf "b.x=%d\n" b.x
;;
```

I get a result which indicates that `b.x` does not alias `a.x`:

```
b.x=42
type t = { mutable x : int; mutable y : int; }
val a : t = {x = 43; y = 123}
val b : t = {x = 42; y = 124}
```

which makes me very happy but I want to make sure that

```
{ e with fi=x }
```

is effectively syntactic sugar for something like

```
(let tmp=e in { f0=tmp.f0; … fi-1=tmp.fi-1; fi=x; fi+1=tmp.fi+1; …; fn=tmp.fn })
```

and that `mutable` fields cannot be backed by a `ref` that an implementation could reuse instead of allocating new mutable storage.

Comment: So you just want us to confirm that 

`{ e with fi=x }`

is effectively syntactic sugar for `(let tmp=e in { f0=tmp.f0; … fi-1=tmp.fi-1; fi=x; fi+1=tmp.fi+1; …; fn=tmp.fn })` ...etc?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, A pointer to other docs or an explanation of how to read these docs would be helpful, but anything from someone who knows what is and is not undefined behavior would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everywhere I've seen, "shallow copy" means, simply transfer all the components over as if by assignment, even in languages where all fields are always mutable, like Java. So in this case `(let tmp=e in { f0=tmp.f0; … fi-1=tmp.fi-1; fi=x; fi+1=tmp.fi+1; …; fn=tmp.fn })` is exactly what it should mean.

Comment: If `mutable` were implemented as syntactic sugar using `ref` so `{ mutable i : int }` is syntactic sugar for `{ i : int ref }` and `{ i = 42 }` when `i` is mutable is syntactic sugar for `{ i = ref 42 }`, then a shallow copy would copy the ref cell.  I can't find the section of the docs which specifies whether the mutable record field is an immutable pointer to an aliasable `ref` that lives outside the record.

Comment: @Mike: In OCaml, `t ref` is sugar for `{mutable contents : t}` (as stated in the manual somewhere), so you can safely assume that `mutable` is not defined in terms of indirection through `ref`. ;)

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, Great.  `mutable` record fields are the mutable storage primitive upon which other abstractions are built.  Thanks alot.  For the record, the manual references are [2.2 Mutable](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/u3-ocaml/ocaml-core.html#mutable) which says "In fact, in OCaml, references are not primitive: they are special cases of mutable records." and that is reiterated in the [Pervasives ocamldoc](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#TYPEref).